How do I set up a trigger to run every 5 minute while testing an app script add-on in a test deployment?
We have set up an Apps Script add-on for Google Sheets, which includes a trigger set to run every 5 minutes. However, during testing in test deployment mode, we were advised to configure the trigger to run at least every 1 hour instead.
We have now set up the trigger to run every 1 hour, but we want to configure it to run every 5 minutes instead.
